# What algorithm does hmmestimate of MATLAB use?

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models

The `hmmtrain()` uses the Baum-Welch algorithm. But there is no mention as to what the `hmmestimate()` uses?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: They are referencing a book called Biological Sequence Analysis, Durbin, Eddy, Krogh, and Mitchison, Cambridge University Press, 1998, inside the function. The chapter concerning parameter estimation is hidden in Google books, but if you can get access to the book you will probably find the answer there.

Comment: Thank you! Can you add this as an answer? Does the algorithm have a name? @Tapio

Comment: I don't know, I only found the source but can not access the whole text. I think you should check it out and answer the question yourself, that would be useful for people searching for the answer and seeing this question later on.